# Failed to fetch multicall chunk on uniswap fork

Tags: gas, uniswap

I'm already forked uniswap interface and refactored it to hit pancakeswap router. Everything working perfectly excepts for an error that i'm experiencing while trying to swap tokens:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4049 
Failed to fetch multicall chunk (2) [{…}, {…}] 56 Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32000}, method="call", transaction={"to":"0x1Ee38d535d541c55C9dae27B12edf090C608E6Fb","data":"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","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.4.5)
    at e.value (index.ts:225)
    at e.value (index.ts:237)
    at S (json-rpc-provider.ts:80)
    at r.<anonymous> (json-rpc-provider.ts:555)
    at c (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:294)
    at Generator.throw (runtime.js:119)
    at s (3.fa1592c2.chunk.js:2)
```

i think that this is an old issue with uniswap forks and although i've lurked on github issues i didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem were in one of the token address!

Comment: can you elaborate? I am also stuck

Comment: yeah 98% sure that the problem was on multicall contract address

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the multicall contract. Make sure that it along with all contract address on constants.tsx is correctly.